# Counting the rows in tuple

Tags: python, sql

I am taking the data from SQL and putting the data in the tuple with `Fetchmany()`. But i am unable to count the rows in the tuple. Below is the code with i am trying.

```
result=cursor.execute("select * from temp where File_name ='ABC')

row = cursor.fetchall()

temp=row.count('FileName')

print(temp)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please `print(result)` and `print(row)` as well?

Comment: I want the count of rows that is extracted in variable "row". As row is tuple, i am unable to get the count. I am not sure how i can use count in tuple without giving any parameter. I have tried converting "row" which a tuple to a list, but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, it looks like you are trying to count the rows in the row tuple returned by `fetchall()`. However, the `count()` method is used to count the occurrences of a specific element in a list or tuple, and it won't work as expected in this case. To count the number of rows in the row tuple, you can use the `len()` function, which returns the length of an object (number of elements).

```
result = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM temp WHERE File_name = 'ABC'")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

row_count = len(rows)
print(row_count)
```

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I am getting the desired result now :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of rows that your query returned just use len function on your row variable.

You can see how fetchall works [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall)

```
row = result.fetchall()
number_of_rows = len(row)

print(number_of_rows)
```